# Angular mock dependency function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've got the following angular module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

Which has the following controller

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, Contacten) {
///snip
   $scope.createContact = function(contactName){
      var newContact = {naam: contactName};
      $scope.contacten.push(newContact);
      Contacten.save($scope.contacten);
      $scope.sideMenuController.close(); <-- This function is from the ionic dependency
      return newContact;
   };
```

I wrote the following test

```
$describe('ContactCtrl createContact add a contact', function() {
  beforeEach(module('ionic'));  
  beforeEach(module('app'));  

  it('It adds a contact to the array', inject(function(Contacten, $rootScope, $controller)   {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
    ctrl = $controller("ContactCtrl", {$scope: scope});

    window.localStorage.clear();
    scope.contacten = [];

    var testContact = {name: "TestPerson" };
    scope.createContact(testContact);
    console.log(scope.contacten)
    expect(Contacten.all().length).toEqual(1);      
    }));
});
```

This throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.sideMenuController.close')
```

Why doesn't the scope in the test file have access to this function while the scope in the controller has no problem accessing this?

Comment: Could you try to instantiate your controller and run a `$scope.$digest()` in a `beforeEach`?